# ArcGIS vs QGIS vs PostGIS projection issue

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, sql, os-mastermap

*Windows 10, ArcGIS Pro, QGIS 2.18, pgAdmin 4-postgreSQL*

I have two (sample area) PostGIS tables in a PostgreSQL database:

building_polys (SRID: 27700) -OS MastermapTopo

address_points (SRID: 4258) -OS AddressBase

I have a project set up in British National Grid projection (27700) in ArcGIS and QGIS too. When my postgis layers are imported into ArcGIS I get the expected result where the point lies within the building polygon:
[image: Layers match]

However when imported into QGIS, the result is wrong:
[image: Layers offset]

I believe this is due to the way QGIS re-projects layers from 4258 to 27700...

This in itself is not an issue, HOWEVER my problem is that using ST_WITHIN statements in PostgreSQL (using pgAdmin) seem to use the QGIS approach...

If I run:

```
SELECT t.*, s.uprn FROM public.building_polys t, public.address_points s WHERE ST_WITHIN(s.wkb_geometry,t.wkb_geometry)
```

It returns nothing. For comparison, if I add a 5 metre search distance on that (using ST_DWITHIN) I do get my expected results:

```
SELECT t.*, s.uprn FROM public.building_polys t, public.address_points s WHERE ST_DWITHIN(s.wkb_geometry,t.wkb_geometry,5)
```

This confirms that postgis recognises an offset just like QGIS.

I decided to apply a transformation of the point data, from 4258 to 27700, to see if that would shift the points into their correct position:

```
ALTER TABLE public.address_points
 ALTER COLUMN wkb_geometry TYPE geometry(Point, 27700)
   USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(wkb_geometry, 4258), 27700);
```

This doesn't help though. It does transform the points to 27700 but they remain in the same position and more importantly, SQL statements still recognise the point as lying outside of the polygon:

[image: After transformation]

How can I get my PostGIS PostgreSQL statements to recognise the spatial position of the data in the same way that ArcGIS does?

Comment: One way maybe to see that transformation ArcGIS is using, and then try to use the same in QGIS.

Comment: EPSG:4285 is surely wrong for data in the UK. BTW the OS adress dataset also contains X and Y coordinates in EPSG:27700.

Comment: Let me play GIS detective: - you imported (or set, as in 'not transformed') the adress geometries with the wrong CRS (coordinates of both are, in fact, EPSG:27700); - in ArcGIS, you loaded the builings first; - ArcGIS sets EPSG:27700 as project CRS; - you load the adresses second and ArcGIS enforces the project CRS --> the adresses coordinates are *accidentally* correctly interpreted (I always hated that 'feature', but this time it (sort of) did the right thing...). QGIS tries to *transform* each layer into the project CRS, and (rightly) fails to interprete the coordinates correctly.

Comment: PostGIS fails for the same reason to find containment. it actually would have also failed, in your first try, even if the adresses were correctly set; pretty much all functions require all geometries to be in the same CRS! the second try (where you transformed) fails due to the wrongly assigned CRS. not sure if the ArcGIS thing holds, AFAIK it always nags when a layer is not in the project CRS. in either way, ArcGIS doesn't simply magic the point in the correct place if they were stored with a wrong projection in PostGIS, so you need to find the issue in the data stored in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

Comment: @enolan projecting the data to 27700 in ArcGIS results in the points remaining in the correct location. Setting the CRS of the layer to 27700 in QGIS results in the points appearing off the coast of Cornwall at 'UK NULL island'.

Comment: @AndreJ AddressBase is delivered in 4258 (sorry not 4285!) see chapter 7 for original GML supply specs https://www.europa.uk.com/resources/os/os-addressbase/addressbase-technical-specification.pdf

Comment: @ThingumaBob hi and thanks for the comment. AddressBase is not 27700 (see my previous comment to andrej. Although there are XYs and LatLongs stored in the metadata, the EPSG is 4258. I will continue to play around with the data to find a solution.

Comment: AddressBase is supplied in both. LAT/LON and British National Grid. X_Coordinate and Y_Coordinate fields are the coordinates in EPSG:27700

Comment: But this is likely a reprojection issue. You can get QGIS to be more accurate using the grid files for transformation https://dragons8mycat.com/2016/09/26/add-ostn15-to-qgis-2-16/

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto When I uploaded my AddressBase GML files to postGIS using ogr2ogr, the lat/long and X/Y fields didn't pull through for some reason... (perhaps gdal and ogr2ogr don't support float fields)... And anyway, just because there are XY fields, doesn't mean the dataset is in 27700.

Comment: AddressBase is captured in British National Grid. It is captured using MasterMap Topo layer which is in British National Grid.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_projections.html & you may have to set it up in QGIS.

Comment: @enolan thanks but my probelm isn't really how it displays in QGIS, it's how it 'displays' and is located in postgis postgreSQL.

Comment: my temporary workaround solution is to load the layer into ArcGIS the use the Project tool to re-project it to 27700. Then upload the result to postgreSQL.